# Generating Reference Numbers then writing them to corresponding workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA script which will generate an unique reference number, then write it to a specific cell in another workbook.

Currently I have a macro which scrubs through multiple workbooks and pulls out the data I need. Is there anyway to make it so a unique reference number is generated and assigned to the data from each workbook, then that number is written in the  in a specified cell in the workbook from where the data was pulled.

Sorry I don't have any code to present as I do not know where to begin with this script

Comment: For a unique number I use a concatenation of the current date and time (including seconds).  Once you have the value it’s easy in VBA to write it to a cell.  Do you have any VBA experience?

Comment: Store a value in a worksheet cell, and increment it each time you need a new ID.

Comment: @tjejojyj Yes I have a little.

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah thats simple enough, but i need it to write back to the file from which the data was pulled.

Comment: OK but what's the specific problem you're having with that?  You have existing code which reads data from each file, so you can add a line to that code to write the reference number to each source file.